# how to solve more inequalities all together instead of one by one by using sagemath?

Tags: sagemath

If I want to solve two or more inequalities in the same input like those ones:

`solve((x-1)<8,x)`

`solve((x-1)<15,x)`

I would like to have the two solution all together. But in the output I have only the solution of the  last inequality.

How to create a vector of inequalities as in put and a vector of solution as output?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to _simultaneously_ solve these systems? That is, you want to view these two inequalities as one system? Or are you saying that you want to solve _multiple systems_ simultaneously. That is, you want to run one command that does the same thing as running both of the commands you gave?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I would like to solve two inequalities or more simultaneously

Comment: Your english is fine! This is the kind of ambiguity that happens all the time ^_^. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add multiple variables, then you can solve separate inequalities with one call to `solve`. For your example:

```
sage: x,y = var('x,y')
sage: solve([x-1 < 8, y-1 < 15], x, y) # solve the list of inequalities for x and y
[[x < 9, y < 16]]
```

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: great thanks :)